# Using my wifi netgear for syncing my file system

Tags: wireless, filesystem, sync

I have a desktop , a laptop and a tab. I have a wired internet connection which is routed through netgear for wifi connection to my laptop and android tablet. Is it possible to sync my files of a particular location in my tablet/laptop with my desktop? I do not want to use the google drive or dropbox as this will consume my network bandwidth(over a long run). I want to use only my wifi netgear router(intranet) without using the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking for [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Usage:

```
rsync -avz /root/temp/ remote_user@192.168.200.10:/home/remote_user/temp/
```

where /root/temp/ is the local directory and /home/remote_user_temp/ is the remote directory where the syncing is done. You will be asked for the remote_user's password.

Note that rsync depends on ssh, which means that you will have to install it on both machines (so as ssh-client/server is installed in both of them so as to do anything you want with rsync from anywhere)

For more information on rsync's options you can

```
man rsync
```

Comment: *"to my laptop and android tablet"* How does this apply to Android?

Comment: yes thats my doubt too. Solved my question to an extent, hackermania.

Comment: Currently I'm using wifi transfer(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&feature=nav_result). But its free version cannot upload files larger than 5 MB.

Comment: I think that rsync works on android too https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to use the google drive or dropbox as this will consume my network bandwidth(over a long run)

First of all, note that Dropbox will use your LAN. It won't go over all of the WAN for syncing files over the local network. It will still use *some* internet bandwidth, but it will just try to find files on your local network. See [LAN Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/help/137/en) on the Dropbox help site:

> LAN sync is a Dropbox feature that speeds syncing dramatically when
>   the file exists on your Local Area Network (LAN).
>
> [...] With LAN syncing, Dropbox will look for the new file on your
>   Local Area Network first, bypassing the need to download the file from
>   Dropbox servers, thus speeding up the syncing process considerably.
>
> LAN sync is an extra advantage for use in locations where computers
>   are networked together over the same router or other local area
>   network.

In case you're looking for a more Dropbox-like, but self-hosted application with a automatic synchronisation of files, the ability to revert to earlier versions, add more machines, etc. then you might consider using [sparkleshare [image: Install Sparkleshare]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sparkleshare). It is available [on Android](https://github.com/NewProggie/SparkleShare-Android) as well.